# What's the best way to create empty/default rows for missing aggregations

Tags: sql

I have a table I want to group over two levels. As the output, I need all the grouping value combinations, such that I end up with zeros where non existant combinations occur. For example, say I have this table:

```
+------+------+
| user | page |
+------+------+
| a    |    1 |
| a    |    1 |
| a    |    2 |
| b    |    2 |
| b    |    3 |
+------+------+
```

I'm after output like this:

```
+------+------+--------+
| user | page | visits |
+------+------+--------+
| a    |    1 |      2 |
| a    |    2 |      1 |
| a    |    3 |      0 |
| b    |    1 |      0 |
| b    |    2 |      1 |
| b    |    3 |      1 |
+------+------+--------+
```

I can achieve this with the following query, but it seems rather heavy handed:

```
WITH 
    users AS (SELECT distinct(user) FROM sometable),
    pages AS (SELECT distinct(page) FROM sometable),
    users_pages_empty AS (SELECT * FROM users CROSS JOIN pages),
    users_pages_full AS (SELECT user, page, count(*) as visits FROM sometable GROUP BY user, page)
SELECT e.user, e.page, coalesce(f.visits, 0) as visits 
FROM users_pages_empty e 
LEFT JOIN users_pages_full f ON e.user=f.user AND e.page=f.page
```

I happen to be using AWS Athena, but I think this is more a generic SQL question than an Athena question.

The performance of this query is fine, it's more the readability/complexity I'm not happy with.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the existing rows and aggregate:

```
select u.user, p.page, count(s.user)
from (select distinct user from sometable) u cross join
     (select distinct page from sometable) p left join
     sometable s
     on s.user = u.user and s.page = p.page
group by u.user, p.page
order by u.user, p.page;
```